How to Resolve ESLint 'Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'never'' Warning in TypeScript?
I got annoying Eslint warning for below two lines.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue ? Any hints are more than welcome!
PS: code is working , but just Eslint warning due to my bad code i guess
item[key as keyof ICollectionMetaColumn] = value
mapping[key as keyof ISynchronizationTargetMapping] 

Eslint warning:
 Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'never'.

sorry for my bad code :-)
function setValue<T extends ICollectionMetaColumn | ISynchronizationTargetMapping, K extends keyof T>(
  index: number,
  key: K,
  value: T[K],
) {
  if (isICollectionMetaColumn(_metaColumns.value[index])) {
    const item = _metaColumns.value[index] as ICollectionMetaColumn
    // here ESLint warning ...
    item[key as keyof ICollectionMetaColumn] = value
    emit('update:columns', unref(_metaColumns))
    if (key === 'columnName' && !value && _metaColumns.value.length === 1)
      emit('update:columns', [])
  }
  else {
    const mapping = _metaColumns.value[index] as ISynchronizationTargetMapping
    // here ESLint warning ...
    mapping[key as keyof ISynchronizationTargetMapping] = value
    emit('update:mapping', unref(_metaColumns))
    if (key === 'destinationField' && !value && _metaColumns.value.length === 1)
      emit('update:mapping', [])
  }
}

function isICollectionMetaColumn(item: ICollectionMetaColumn | ISynchronizationTargetMapping) {
  return !('destinationField' in item)
}


const metaColumns = ref<(ICollectionMetaColumn | ISynchronizationTargetMapping)[]>

const _metaColumns = ref<(ICollectionMetaColumn | ISynchronizationTargetMapping)[]>(unref(metaColumns).length > 0
  ? unref(metaColumns)
  : Array.isArray(unref(metaColumns)[0]) && isICollectionMetaColumn(unref(metaColumns)[0])
    ? [{ columnName: '', type: 'varchar' }] as ICollectionMetaColumn[]
    : [{ destinationField: '', path: '' }] as ISynchronizationTargetMapping[],
)


interface ICollectionMetaColumn {
  columnName: string
  type: 'bigint' | 'binary' | 'bit' | 'boolean'
}

interface ISynchronizationTargetMapping{
 destinationField: string,
 path: string
}


Could you please provide a minimal reproducable example. You code contains lots of undeclared types/functions/variables. It's very uncomfortable for people trying to debug your code and might lead to unprecise answers.

Think about this T extends IFoo | IBar, K extends keyof T. If T can be either interface, K can be a key that appears in any interface. So if IFoo is {a: number} and IBar is {b: string}, when T: IFoo and K = "b", both T and K are valid, but T[K] is not.
